# HTML checkboxes and input options

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am having 10 checkbox (multiple option)Html form. If user select Option1 a text box should appear against that option asking to enter number.
Similarly if no checkbox is selected there should be no text box.
What should be the sample code idea?

Comment: And where exactely is your problem? SO is not made for coding your stuff.

Comment: You should at least add the HTML and CSS. People are here to help you, not to spend all time doing the all codding!

Comment: Not require any coding, just html/css terminology or type to be used in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create inputs on the fly you can use the following:

```js
$(".myCheckbox").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parent().append('<input id="checkboxInput'+value+'" type="text" maxlength="254" name="checkboxInput'+value+'">');
    } else {
        $('#checkboxInput'+value).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="checkboxWrapper">
    <input class="myCheckbox" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="someName[]" value="1" />
    <label for="checkbox1">Value 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkboxWrapper">
    <input class="myCheckbox" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="someName[]" value="2" />
    <label for="checkbox2">Value 2</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkboxWrapper">
    <input class="myCheckbox" id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="someName[]" value="3" />
    <label for="checkbox3">Value 3</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet on what you are looking for. It is not "just" html/css terminology. But also you'll need understanding of Javascript or at least JQuery.

```js
$('.checkbox-group input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
 var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(target).fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.checkbox-group{
    position:relative;
}

.checkbox-group input[type='text']{
    display:none;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
.
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <div class="checkbox-group">
        <input type='checkbox' value='Name' data-target="#inputname" /> Name <br/>
        <input type='text' id='inputname' placeholder="your name" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="checkbox-group">
        <input type='checkbox' value='Email' data-target="#inputemail" /> Email <br/>
        <input type='text' id='inputemail' placeholder="your email" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="checkbox-group">
        <input type='checkbox' value='Phone' data-target="#inputphone" /> Phone <br/>
        <input type='text' id='inputphone' placeholder="your phone" />
    </div>
        
    <div class="checkbox-group">
        <input type='checkbox' value='Age' data-target="#inputage" /> Age <br/>
        <input type='text' id='inputage' placeholder="your age" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better if the text is a label for the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".whatever").click(function() {
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $(this).closest("li").find('.toggle').show(500);
} else {
     $(this).prop('checked',false);
      $(this).closest("li").find('.toggle').hide(500);
}
});
```

Make a div and give it class="toggle". This is your disappearing div. Add class .whatever to input tag. Should get you started in right path.